# Remove first column (#) of Yii2 GridView

Tags: yii2

Does someone know how to remove the first column (`<th>#</th>`) of a Yii2 GridView?
Probably a simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: which column? provide more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],` from `columns => [ ... ]` of `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
which is inside the GridView::widget, columns section.